# Make multiple dependent data validations update the dropdown when validation values are changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script in place to populate three different columns with differing date ranges (based on a filter formula) that are dependent on the date entered in column AM. Right now this is set up to adjust the data validation dropdown list ONLY if the cell in column AM is edited. I'd like it to also adjust the data validation dropdown list if the validation values themselves change (aka if I edit the filter formula at all).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var mainWsName = "PRT_Tracker";
  var appointmentWsName = "Visit_Windows";
  var firstLevelColumn = 39;
  var secondLevelColumn = 41;
  var thirdLevelColumn = 45;
  var fourthLevelColumn = 50;
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
  var wsWindows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(appointmentWsName);
  var appointment = wsWindows.getRange(2,1,wsWindows.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues(); 

function onEdit(e) {

  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow(); //return row of active cell
  var c =activeCell.getColumn(); // return col of active cell
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r >1) {
  applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  } if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r >1) {
  applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  } if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r >1) {
  applyThirdLevelValidation(val,r);
  }

}

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){

      var filteredAppointment =  appointment.filter(function(a){return a[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredAppointment.map(function(a){return a[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){

      var filteredAppointment =  appointment.filter(function(a){return a[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredAppointment.map(function(a){return a[2]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
}

function applyThirdLevelValidation(val,r){

      var filteredAppointment =  appointment.filter(function(a){return a[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredAppointment.map(function(a){return a[3]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,fourthLevelColumn); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell); 
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell) {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: What's keeping your from achieving your goal?

Comment: Hi ! What is your exact question or doubt here? Where are you having issues in? Also, sharing an example sheet *with no sensitive data* could be really helpful to be able to test and try to solve your issue. Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi @cooper, I'm just not sure how to get the data validation list to change automatically, right now I have to go back to the corresponding cell and edit the data in there in order for it to read a new list of validations. For example if I use this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iOtxDrKPN1H-Medm2wLYhxtQXroUSXfjd4AezecABJk/edit#gid=1859928417 and change the scheduler tab to only have availability on Fridays as opposed to other days of the week, I want the validation list to read that automatically, not just after I update the Start Date column. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, I have this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iOtxDrKPN1H-Medm2wLYhxtQXroUSXfjd4AezecABJk/edit#gid=1859928417 are you able to access it?